# How can I copy cells from one row on Sheet to two different rows on different sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel workbook I have a 'data sheet' that is 294 columns wide, and contains lots of data for football matches. **Each row** on that data sheet corresponds to the data for **one match**. Due to the amount of columns the data is almost unreadable so to filter the data, I have written a VBA code which currently loops through all of the data and when various criteria for a match are met it adds the data to columns in a row on a different sheet e.g.
column A (home team), column B (away team), column C (some data), column D (some data) etc...

I want to change it so that instead of having **one match in one row**, I'd like to split it into **one match in two rows**. The simple reason for this is so that I gain a bit of space and it becomes more readable.

So for example i want it to read :

ROW 3 (home team) and the columns hold all the data for the home team.
ROW 4 (away team) and the columns hold all the data for the away team.

Here is my original VBA:

```
Sub LTATrades()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, fs As Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, x As Long
    Set fs = Sheets("Filters")
    Set ds = Sheets("Data")
    LastRow = ds.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ClearSelections
    SortData
    DeleteCF
    For x = 4 To LastRow
        If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 3)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 4)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 5)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 81)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 91)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 82)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 92)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 83)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 93)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 84)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 94)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 85)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 96)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 95)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 86)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 88)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 98)
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 58).Value / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 58).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 72).Value / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 72).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
            Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        End If
    Next x
    ResetCFLTA
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And now, here is what i have tried to make it work as i want...

```
Sub LTATradesTest()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, fs As Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, x As Long
    Set fs = Sheets("Filters")
    Set ds = Sheets("Data")
    LastRow = ds.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ClearSelections
    SortData


    For x = 4 To LastRow
    If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 3)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 4)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 5)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 81)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 91)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 82)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 92)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 83)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 93)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 84)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 94)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 85)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 96)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 95)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 86)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 88)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = ds.Cells(x, 98)
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 58).Value / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 58).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 72).Value / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" & ds.Cells(x, 72).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
        Sheets("LTA").Cells(Sheets("LTA").Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" & (ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) & "/" & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me achieve what i want?

There is a slight snag. As you can see the first piece of data is common to both teams (it is the name of the league) Is there anyway to tell excel to merge the two rows for column B?

Regards

Comment: *This does not work though.* - Posting a [mcve] will help you get more attention to your problem.

Comment: I have rectified this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## LTA Trades Test

```
Option Explicit

Sub LTATradesTest()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastRow As Long, fs As Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, x As Long
    Dim ltaLR As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set fs = .Worksheets("Filters")
        Set ds = .Worksheets("Data")
    End With

    LastRow = ds.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ClearSelections
    SortData

    For x = 4 To LastRow

        If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= _
            fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTA")

                ltaLR = .Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

                .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Value = ds.Cells(x, 3)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Resize(2, 1).Merge

                .Cells(ltaLR, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 4)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 5)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 81)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 91)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 82)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 92)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 83)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 93)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 84)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 94)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 85)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 96)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 95)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 86)
                .Cells(ltaLR, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 88)
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 98)

                .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value _
                    / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value _
                    / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 58).Value _
                    / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & ds.Cells(x, 58).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 72).Value _
                    / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & ds.Cells(x, 72).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"

                .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 229).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 257).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR, "N").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + _
                    ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "N").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 55).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR, "O").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 56).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "O").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 59).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR, "P").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 144).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "P").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 147).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                    + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) & "/" _
                    & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"

            End With

        End If

    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. Could i ask is it possible to merge the cells in Column B with the row below (seeing as it is empty)? It may be the case that for some of the data i want to merge the cells as well as i will have a common statistic for both teams....

Comment: Just add this after the "B" Line: '.Cells(ltaLR, "B").Resize(2, 1).Merge' (without the quotes) and delete the commented second "B" Line.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your help. Everything is working as wanted!